# Understanding the tables referred to in a BigQuery array cross join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know the namespace isn't the correct term for this but it conveys what I'm trying to understand. Take this query:

```
WITH Movies AS (
  SELECT 'Titanic' AS title,
  1997 AS year, 
  ['Drama',' Romance'] AS Genres
)
SELECT title, year, Movies.Genres FROM Movies, Movies.Genres where Genres='Drama'
```

[image]

But then using `Movies.Genres` instead of `Genres` gives a different result:

```
WITH Movies AS (
  SELECT 'Titanic' AS title,
  1997 AS year, 
  ['Drama',' Romance'] AS Genres
)
SELECT title, year,Genres FROM Movies, Movies.Genres where Genres='Drama'
```

[image]

Why does that occur? Additionally, is this standard (ISO) SQL, or is this just how BigQuery performs array-unnesting and joins?

Comment: Screenshots look identical...

Comment: @SergeyGeron sorry, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to use array in cross (or other types of) join - you have below options

1. `from tableA cross join unnest(array) as element`
2. `from tableA, unnest(array) as element` -- here comma is actually shortcut for cross join
3. if array is a column of tableA, you can use yet another shortcut (now for unnest)
   `from tableA, tableA.array as element`

the benefit of using UNNEST is that you can define OFFSET - like in below example

```
from tableA, unnest(array) as element with offset
```

Having offset is extremely important in many use cases
In my practice  - i am using all of above options depends on specific case

Now, as of difference in two queries:

So, the first query

```
SELECT title, year, Movies.Genres 
FROM Movies, Movies.Genres 
where Genres='Drama'
```

is equivalent to below (notice aliase)

```
SELECT title, year, Movies.Genres 
FROM Movies, Movies.Genres as Genres
where Genres='Drama'
```

`Genres` in `where Genres='Drama'` refers to element from implicitly unnested Movies.Genres - so one of element is `Drama` which returns 1 element out of total two
And, now trick is that in select statement you explicitly calling out `Movies.Genres` which is the original array in  that row - so that explains the output

You can try below to kind of confirm above explanation

```
SELECT title, year, Movies.Genres
FROM Movies, Movies.Genres as Genres
where Genres in ('Drama', ' Romance')
```

for above output will be

[image]

While above explained the output for first query - I hope it is now clear why second query returns actual genre (Drama) instead of array

Hope this helped in understanding differences :o)

Comment: thanks, this is great. Is this syntax specific to BigQuery, or do you know of any other DBMS that have something similar (postgres, sqlserver, oracle)?

Answer (score 1):

First query selects the `Genres` field itself from `Movies` Table, thus we see 2 rows because it has 2 values.
In the second query `Genres` is now considered to be a row from unnested Movies.Genres.
To remove this disambiguity probably makes sense to use `as`:

`SELECT title, year, G FROM Movies, Movies.Genres as G where G = 'Drama'`

Comment: I see, so BQ automatically aliases the joined table -- for example: `Movies.Genres` --> `Movies.Genres as Genres` ?

Comment: yep, looks like it is